# How to stop recursive looping functions from outside in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

In my application, I have given the ability for the user to start multiple instances of a looping recursive function. Currently, each function will continue forever and I need a way to explicitly end each one. Thinking about this I imagine I would need to keep a running array of processes and store a unique id for each process and associate an isRunning variable with it but I can't quite wrap my head around how to accomplish this.

This function on the server side get's called from the front end whenever a user makes a POST to my API and will continue to call itself at random intervals.

```
function scrapeAtRandomInterval(id, search_terms, category, location, min, max) {

  // Not currently using the id param as I don't need it for anything on the server side but thought it might come in handy to solve this issue.

  scrape(location, category, search_terms, min, max);

  var rand = randomIntBetweenBounds(0, 3600000 / 3);
  setTimeout(function() {
    scrapeAtRandomInterval(id, search_terms, category, location, min, max);  
  }, rand);  
}
```

When the user makes a DELETE request, I need a way to stop the function call associated with the POST that called the function. Again, I imagine by referencing an array of objects each with the id and a bool flag and then maybe inside the function I could add a check if isRunning?

Comment: If you want to be able to stop the currently running timer, you need to store the timerID that is returned from `setTimeout()` in some data structure that you can get to from the outside.  Then you can call `clearTimeout()` on that timerID.  There is no other way to stop the timer unless you kill the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I imagine by referencing an array of objects each with the id ...

Searching an array is `O(n/2)` average, using an object as a hashatable is `O(1)` and therefore a lot faster, so using an array works, but it is slow (for many processes running).

> ... and a bool flag and then maybe inside the function I could add a check if isRunning?

Or even easier, you just store the timer under the id and cancel that when needed, for that you need an object to store the timer ids based on the processes id:

```
const timers = {};
```

Then when setting a new timeout store its id:

```
timers[id] = setTimeout(...);
```

Then to clear it, just do:

```
clearTimeout(timers[id]);
delete timers[id]; // allow the engine to optimize the hashtable
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. If optimizing the hash table is important, I wonder if `delete timers[id]` is a better way to go.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was heading towards I was just having trouble with the implementation. Think I got it working now, this is great. Should I be removing the id from the hashtable altogether though?

Comment: Why not use a Map object?  One could use a Symbol for the key for unique keys.